# How can I know the key press value during phone call by Twilio

Tags: twilio

How can I know that, user press 1 or 2 or 3 during phone call by twilio. After pressing the key (1 or 2 or 3) user will get options. Like if he/she presses 1 user will listen some text, if user presses 2 he/she will redirect to another person and so on. 
 I can do this individually i.e. I can set a message or I can set a phone number of user1 and I make a call to user2. When User2 receives the call he/she will be redirected to user1.
 But I can not do this by the pressing value.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do this using the `<Gather>` verb in TwiML. `<Gather>` allows you to set how many keypresses you want to record and then a URL to redirect to once you have received those keypresses. When Twilio makes the request to the next URL you will get a `Digits` parameter in the request which will contain the keys pressed.

Here's the [documentation for `<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) and a [tutorial for a phone menu](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/phonemenu). Hope this helps!